# Youtube API not showing all videos

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm quite new to Youtube API and I've been trying to retrieve a list of the most watched video musics. The code seems to work fine, but it doesn't show all results (some videos are missing)

Current link/code:

> [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?type=video&part=snippet&order=viewCount&maxResults=50&videoCategory=10&key={key}](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?type=video&part=snippet&order=viewCount&maxResults=50&videoCategory=10&key=%7Bkey%7D)

It shows up to 50 videos but some are missing and I don't know why (I even checked and they also are 'music' category)
Ex: Justin Bieber Baby (1,546,982,110 views) Ariana Grande Problem (955,619,144 views) etc..
Thanks!

Comment: Same issue with https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&key=AIzaSy... The idea was that [most viewed videos are musics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-viewed_YouTube_videos) and we could quickly check with [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint.